# Getting OpenLayers pixel value of DEM layer?

Tags: openlayers

I am working in OpenLayers and need to get pixel value of DEM layer to get the altitude of the place.

Can you guide me?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: API docs can also be helpful: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#getPixelFromCoordinate